# Constellation Diagram : Fitting Text in Bubbles

Tags: diagrams, smartdiagram

Code Used :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\smartdiagram[constellation diagram]{Suggested Solutions
,Hardware Optimization Techniques,Software Optimization Techniques~/\\ Add}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

How can I fix this output so that text fills the bubbles in a neater way 
[image]

The arrow lines must not collide , the text must fill the bubble neater and if possible the arrows are needed to be emerging from the middle bubble and not converging to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of available options via `\smartdiagramset` (see manual for complete list). If you also add linebreaks (`\\`) at useful places you can get this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\smartdiagramset{
  planet text width=2.5cm, % text width of central node
  satellite text width=2.5cm, % text width of side nodes
  distance planet-text=2mm, % padding around text in central node
  distance planet-satellite=4.5cm, % distance from central node to side nodes
}
\smartdiagram[constellation diagram]{
  Suggested Solutions,
  Hardware\\Optimization\\Techniques,
  Software\\Optimization\\Techniques/\\ Add
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @HasanHammoud I just updated the code by the way, if you haven't seen it.